# Handling asynchronous responses in node on server side

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, request

I am trying to build a simple node service that

- Handles a GET request from a web client
- Parses the params submitted
- Uses those params to query another REST service asynchronously
- Returns the REST service results back to the original GET request.

I'm just getting started with asynchronous programming in node, in general I'm struggling to understand how to preserve scope between asynchronous calls.

Basically - how do I send the JSON service 'result' back to the original GET request via the 'req'?

I'm using Express and [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), the route handler looks like:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
var params = req.query;
var queryParam= params.queryParm;

var restURL =  "http://some-json-service.com?queryParam=" + queryParam;

var request = require('request');

request(restURL, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(body);
        // ? How do I send result back to the req?
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can literally return the response, so where you have your comment you will do:

```
request(restURL, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = JSON.parse(body);
      res(result)
  }
})
```

the problem with this approach is that your client request will be pending a response from the second service which is fine if it has to be done. Just be aware of the delay that you might be causing.

Also make sure in case of an error you also return a response.

This seems simple enough, so let me know if I didn't fully understand your question.

Cheers.

Vitor.

Comment: Ok I see- I just find that so weird, how is res in scope in that anonymous function?

Comment: Also does that block on the server side or otherwise bad practice for server perf?

Comment: **1)** I just got one of the first links I found: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/. The inner scope can see the outer scope (99%), but the opposite doesn't work. That's why you would use an anonymous function in the first place. Using a function reference would not let you do this.

**2)** Well, if you have to do it and if you guarantee that you fail quickly in case the second service is slow it should be fine. As a service provider you expose an API, what you do in the back it's up to you, and most services will have subsequent calls.

Comment: Also found [this](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), which seems like good background...